# Laravel AJAX 500 Internal Error with no message

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, server

I have built a report which is calculating complex numbers and i've used ajax.
The code works perfectly on my localhost but on the server it throws 500 internal error with no message. I tried to use `dd` after each block of the code and it was this part where it throws the error

```
$decoded_needs = [];
  foreach ($needs_teacher as $needs) {
    $decoded_needs[] = json_decode($needs->training_needed);
  }
  if (empty($decoded_needs)) {
    $training_needs_teacher = array(['0' => 'None']);
  } else {
    $sanitized_needs = [];
    foreach ($decoded_needs as $key => $items) {
      foreach ($items as $index => $item) {
        foreach ($item as $name => $bit) {
          $sanitized_needs[$name][] = $bit;
        }
      }
    }

$s_standards = [];
$s_sub_category = [];

// dd() works here

foreach ($sanitized_needs['standard'] as $skey => $standard) {
  $sname = DB::table('lesson_observation_teacher_standards')->where('id', $standard)->first()->name;
  $s_standards[] = $sname;
    foreach ($sanitized_needs['sub_category'] as $key => $substandard) {
      $name = DB::table('lesson_observation_teacher_standard_categories')->where('id', $substandard)->first()->name;
       if ($key == $skey) {
         $s_sub_category[$sname][] = $name;
       }
    }
}
// but not here 
$training_needs_teacher = [];
foreach ($s_sub_category as $key => $index) {
  foreach ($index as $items) {
    $training_needs_teacher[$key] = array_count_values($index);
  }
}

$sanitized_needs = [];
foreach ($training_needs_teacher as $key => $items) {
  foreach ($items as $index => $item) {
    $sanitized_needs[$key . ":" . count($items)][] = $index . ":" . $item;
  }
}
$training_needs_teacher = $sanitized_needs;
}
```

I know i could have used `WhereIn` in many cases but i need the duplicate items. I just want to know if there's a way to fix this problem?
Please Note that my ajax includes the csrf token.

Comment: It is likely then that your localhost has additional PHP extensions which aren't on your server - make a php file put `<?php php_info(); ?>` on both the server and the local machine and compare differences. - if you have root access try running `apt-get install php-common` or (CentOS) `yum install php-common`

Comment: @JackWright thanks i'll try that

Comment: @Areg Please use select method for select  `name`. See below answer.

Comment: There usually is an entry in `storage/logs/laravel.log` that could give hints on what went wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the path to DB

I've been through this issue and you must triple check paths, in your local environment probably your site is at the root path so DB:: works fine but in production you should put something before the DB reference like \rootFolder\DB::

I hope it helps.

Comment: It is set correctly and its on `APP_ENV=production`

Comment: Please try replacing DB:: with \DB:: and let us know if the results change.

Comment: @Areg As you said in the localhost working fine. This is wrong!! That is also not working  in localhost without use `\DB::` OR   `use DB;` MAKE SURE..

Comment: @AmitSenjaliya you need to chill firstly. Secondly it DID worked on localhost